# XmlReader XSD validation fails on email regex with an _

Tags: c#, regex, xsd-validation

We have the following regex pattern in our XSD

```
    <xsd:restriction base='xsd:string'>
        <xsd:pattern value='([\w\-\.]+)@(([\w]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,15})'/>
    </xsd:restriction>
```

And do the standard .Net XSD validation against it.

```
        var validationErrors = new List<string>();

        // Set the validation settings.
        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
        {
            ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema,
            Schemas = schemaSet
        };
        settings.ValidationEventHandler += (sender, e) => {
            validationErrors.Add(e.Message);
            };

        // Create the XmlReader object.
        var xmlString = AsString(input);


        var sr = new StringReader(xmlString);
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(sr, settings))
        {
            // Parse the file. 
            while (reader.Read()) ;
        }

        if (validationErrors.Any())
        {
            throw new ValidationException(validationErrors.ToArray());
        }
```

The email your_name@mydomain.com  is a valid email according to the regex the xsd validation declares it as invalid. When removing the _ it works.

I cannot alter the regex pattern since it is an external xsd we have to use.
I am not able to find the source of this issue or how to solve it.

Comment: The regular expression there does indeed validate `your_name@mydomain.com`, so it must be in the way you use it. Can you post a complete sample app including the xsd?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a know issue with XML validation

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5b7bb8e3-f9e9-42bd-a90a-a8498852abe9/whenever-there-is-underscore-82208221-in-the-email-address-the-xml-validation-failed?forum=xmlandnetfx

Solved it by catching the validation callback and performing a manual regex check:

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
        doc.Validate(schemaSet, (o, e) =>
        {
            var elem = o as XElement;
            if(elem != null && elem.Name.LocalName.Equals("email"))
            {
                var regex = @"([\w\-\.]+)@(([\w]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,15})";
                var match = Regex.Match(elem.Value, regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                if (!match.Success)
                {
                    validationErrors.Add(e.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                validationErrors.Add(e.Message);
            }
        });

        if (validationErrors.Any())
        {
            throw new ValidationException(validationErrors.ToArray());
        }
```